# Maintaing a map of buffered stream and closing in the end

Tags: java

My applications does continuous disk i/o through 10 threads. The cpu profile is coming very high around 100%, i was planning to make it to 1 separate writer thread.

Also I was thinking if i can maintain a Cache of Buffered Writers and so do not have to continuously open the streams. Does anyone see a problem in this

But I am unsure of where to put the close the writer. Secondly if the writer are not closed will there be a problem.

Thanks

Comment: Disk I/O is unlikely to exhaust your CPU-cycles. Are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: I agreee with Bjorn. suggest you run your program in a profiler to see where its spending it's cpu cycles.

Comment: The threads are writing in the order of 10k lines per minute. And every time I am opening and closing the writers.  But thanks, I will profile the app further

Comment: Why can't each of the threads keep their own writer?  If they are writing to the same file then why don't they share a single writer?

Comment: They are writing to separate files. I have added a sleep of 1 seconds in the writer threads and performance has drastically improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing short strings to the writers very often, opening a new writer might indeed be a waste of time. One issue to be aware of is that if you keep the streams open, other threads trying to write to the same file may fail. From the FileOutputStream documentation:
`Some platforms, in particular, allow a file to be opened for writing by only one FileOutputStream (or other file-writing object) at a time.`
Also, make sure you put the closing statement in a `finally` clause.

PS Björn is right, IO is unlikely to show up as CPU usage. Run a profile to work out what the app is actually doing

Comment: But I am unsure of where to put the close block as the writer threads needs to continuously run.

Comment: I maintained the map of the writers and closing them at the exit. Additionally i have added a sleep of 1 seconds in the writer thread. These changes have brought down the load

Answer (score 0):

IO itself is unlikely to cause CPU load.

The character encoding conversions involved when converting strings from Java's internal representation to UTF8, ISO-Latin-1 or whatever the encoding it is that you are using, however does cause CPU load.

10000 lines per minute isn't that much, though. Only about 7000 characters per second (for 40 character lines). Or was that 10000 lines for each thread?

Comment: The number of lines per thread with 1000 character on each line

Comment: Oh, that should do it. :) You are converting 1.7 million characters per second.

Comment: :) So I am planning to create a map of Files and Buffered Writers. So that writers are only created once. The writer thread only exits when the application closes. Do i need to close the Buffered Writers. And how to close them as using finalizers is not a good practice

Comment: Flushing buffers and closing writers and files is a good practise and you should do that. When your app is being closed, you should stop your thread in a controlled manner and close the writers when the thread is stopping. It makes sense to have the code that closes the writers in the same class that creates the writers. You should calll that code from the writer thread.